# Dúvida Case SqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou usando o seguinte case:

```
 CASE WHEN RESPOSTA.CD_RESPOSTA = 1 THEN 'ATENDE'
      WHEN RESPOSTA.CD_RESPOSTA = 2 THEN 'NÃO ATENDE'
      ELSE 'NÃO APLICÁVEL' END AS DS_RESPOSTA
```

Tenho no valor de RESPOSTA.CD_RESPOSTA: 2. O campo é um Int, not null.

Porém sempre está me retornando 'NÃO APLICÁVEL'. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Teríamos que ver a consulta onde você está usando. Responder isso sem ver o cenário completo seria somente baseado em chute. Se é para chutar: `RESPOSTA` pode ser `null`.

Comment: Você está usando Azure ou é local?

Comment: Sua consulta está ok se for somente o que você exibiu. Verifique se você possui valores iguais a 1 ou 2 e se o `where` da sua query não está errado, veja um exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/90e9d/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça um tratamento de conversão para o campo conforme o exemplo abaixo. Desta forma é possível garantir qual dado existe na origem do dado. Conforme os resultados, você pode tratar a origem do dado para não ser necessária a conversão.

```
 CASE 
  WHEN CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(RESPOSTA.CD_RESPOSTA, 0)) = 1 THEN 'ATENDE'
  WHEN CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(RESPOSTA.CD_RESPOSTA, 0)) = 2 THEN 'NÃO ATENDE'
  ELSE 'NÃO APLICÁVEL' END AS DS_RESPOSTA
```